# How to prevent Deadlock with Usermanager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I have a registration page on blazor (server). On that Page I want to implement a register function using AspnetCor.Identity

This is the Method: (_usermanager is of type AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<>)

```
  public bool Register(RegisterUser regUser)
    {
        var newUser = new ApplicationUser { Email = regUser.Mail, UserName = regUser.Mail};           
        var sd= _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "password").Result;
        if (!sd.Succeeded)
        {                
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The method is called from within HandleValidSubmit on the blazor-page:

```
<EditForm Model="@_registerUser" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
//...
</EditForm>
@code {
      private void HandleValidSubmit()
        {
            if (identity.Register(_registerUser)) {
              NaviationManager.NavigateTo($"/manage/registersent");
            }
        }
}
```

When Registration fails it works just as designed returning false. But when registration would be fine I end up in a Deadlock at `_userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "password").Result;`

When I do not try to make the async-call synchronous and replace the call by `_userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "password")` (and simply ignore any return value) the user gets created without an issue.

How should I handle an async-call with return-value from within `HandleValidSubmit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make everything `async` - returning `Task`s and `await`ing them as appropriate. Don't call `.Result` or `.Success`. Let the compiler help you write better async code.

For instance make `HandleValidSubmit` async.

```
private async void HandleValidSubmit()
{
    if (await identity.RegisterAsync(_registerUser)) 
    {
        NaviationManager.NavigateTo($"/manage/registersent");
    }
}
```

`async void` should be only used for event-type things since they are akin to "fire and forget".

Comment: Ah. I did not expect that HandleValidSubmit could be async :)

Comment: Shouldn't `HandleValidSubmit` then return a `Task`?

Comment: @Nkosi it depends on how `OnValidSubmit` is implemented.